# Using windows DLLs in a portable app

Tags: c++, windows, linux, dll, portability

I have built a windows C++ application that I'd like to port to linux. The main reasons to do this is ease of system maintenance for our IT staff. Apart from the one windows machine that runs this application we're a linux only operation.

The reason this application was built in-, and runs on- windows is that it uses a windows API (dll and header) to connect to a server belonging to an external party. This connection uses some proprietary protocol that I don't really want to mess with, (and I think I'm contractually not allowed to) so I'm stuck with the .dll.

This dll is windows only because of (I suspect) windows sockets specific code in the dll. Apart from that it doesn't do a whole lot of advanced stuff. Is there a way somewhere between just running the app on linux in WINE and sniffing out the protocol and reimplementing the DLL myself that will allow me to get this application to run on a linux machine?

This idea got inspired by this [item about QT creator](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2008/10/31/qt-creator-tech-preview-released/) so any solution that allows me to play with that would be extra cool.

Comment: Wine is so complete nowadays, so the easiest might be to just run such programs in Wine. If you can port the program to the mingw toolchain, you can still maintain it and run it on Linux only, no Windows needed at all. You can use the standard gnu make and everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most obvious middle ground would be to use [Winelib](http://www.winehq.org/site/docs/winelib-guide/index). I do not know if it can link directly to a native DLL, but if not you probably could load it with `LoadLibrary()`.

You could then split your application in two parts: a wrapper which only calls the DLL, and the rest of the code talking to your wrapper. You could have both in separate processes, and thus only the wrapper would have to be compiled with Winelib. The rest of the application could then use whatever framework you want.